# iText font setting for phrase

Tags: itext

I am using iText 5.5 to generate pdf files.i am trying to make the header font bold,but its not working.
I have used the Phrase to set the header content and set the font for phrase.
please help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no iText 5.5, so I'm presuming you're using v. 5.0.5. You're off to a good start, iText is the best OSS library out there.

There is an example of how to use the header here: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=103 If you make the header Phrase bold, you'll have your header with bold text. I *strongly* suggest that you use the example's code so you can see how it works. Make it bold, then copy the code over to your project. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62089354/itext-font-set-to-phrase-not-being-reflected?newreg=b85ca57aa4b64af089adc427f779e802) you can not edit the font already set, but you can create a new phrase by copying old contents and set the new font in it.

The following worked for me:

```
Phrase existingPhrase = pdfpCell.getPhrase();
// this step created the required font for me
Font font = getFontFormat(); 
Paragraph newPhrase = new Paragraph(existingPhrase.getContent(), font);
pdfpCell.setPhrase(newPhrase);
```