# iText Font set to Phrase not being reflected

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to add font to phrase, I am using iText 5. Font is not being reflected in text that is being display for which I am trying to set.

Let me know If anybody came across the same.

```
private static void addDataToCell(PdfPTable table, String cellData, int border, Font font) {

    final Phrase phrase = new Phrase(cellData);
    if (font != null) {
      phrase.setFont(font);
    }
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(phrase);

    cell.setBorder(border);
    cell.setUseAscender(true);
    cell.setUseDescender(true);

    cell.setPaddingLeft(3);
    cell.setPaddingBottom(3);
    cell.setPaddingTop(3);
    cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    table.addCell(cell);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer is in below link
 https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/faq/fonts/itext-5-legacy/why-cant-i-set-font-phrase

In short, we need to set font while creating Phrase, not afterwards like with `.setFont`

```
new Phrase(cellData, font);
```